# reconnect web socket if it is closed

Tags: websocket, angular7

My web socket connection code :

```
  public connect(): Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(this.url);

    }
    this.ws.onerror = () => {
      this.close();
      let refresh = setInterval(() => {
        this.subject = null;
        this.connect();
        this.ws.onopen = () => {
          clearInterval(refresh)
        }
      }, 5000);
    }

    return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url: string){
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    const observable = Observable.create((obs: Subject<MessageEvent>) => {
      this.ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      this.ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
      this.ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
      this.ws.onclose = function () {
        console.log("trying to reconnect");
        this.connect();
      }

      return this.ws.close.bind(this.ws);
    });

    const observer = {
      next: (data: any) => {
        if (this.ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      }
    };
    return Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }
```

I want to reconnect web socket if connection closes. At the moment the function gets truggered when i stop the web socket. BUt is not connecting again .I See error  "this.connect is not a function" .How to work with angular recursive functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `function` keyword to create your callback when using `this` inside of it if you aren't aware of how it changes the `this` reference depending on the execution context, use **arrow function** instead

To make it reconnect, change this

```
this.ws.onclose = function () {
    console.log("trying to reconnect");
    this.connect();
}
```

To this

```
this.ws.onclose = () => {
    console.log("trying to reconnect");
    this.subject = null;
    this.connect();
}
```

Comment: can you also update how to call this function every X seconds?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?